# I cannot update the totals in my dynamic Table (it shows undefined for the new added input)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, undefined, calculation

When I add a new item to my grocery list, and then if I change the number value in the table of the new item. It will give NaN (Not a number) After going with some console.logs trough my code I find out that if I log in eentjeMeer function (which is the function called when I click the number value)

that products[i].waarde they are all defined except the new added item, it is undefined.

but inputs[i].value they are also all defined plus the new added item. So the calculation cannot be made. And then it will result in the total column to NaN as you can see.

Why does it get undefined ? Why does it not see it ? Why does it get NaN ?

For clarification aantal=Quantity and prijs=Value, I want it to calculate the total. Which it does correctly when I add a new item. But not when I want to change the value of the new item in the table.

(It works for the original items in the array)

Code Snippet here:

```js
const myTable = document.getElementById('table')
let products = [ 
    { omschrijving: "Brood" , waarde: 1 , aantal:3 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Brocolli" , waarde: 0.99 , aantal: 2 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Krentenbollen" , waarde: 1.20 , aantal: 4 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Noten" , waarde: 2.99 , aantal: 2 , total: 0}
]
///Update totals in tabel
TabelTotals();
function TabelTotals() {
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].total = products[i].waarde * products[i].aantal;  
}

}
Alles();
function Alles(){
//Totaal alle producten 
const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
   return productCal.total + currentTotal
}, 0);
document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2); 
}
////Table /////Headers
const headerTexts = ['Name', 'Prijs', 'Aantal', 'Totaal'];
const t = document.createElement('table');
t.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
t.querySelector('thead').appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

for (var i = 0; i < headerTexts.length; i++) {
    const heading = document.createElement('td');
    heading.textContent = headerTexts[i];
    t.querySelector('thead tr').appendChild(heading);
}
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(t);
//Rows
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var s = products[i];
    var r = document.createElement('tr');

    r.dataset.productID = s.id; //ff beter kijken wat dit is, dit is wel cool.
    r.id = s.omschrijving + "--row"; 

    var omschrijvingCell = document.createElement('td');
    omschrijvingCell.textContent = s.omschrijving;
    omschrijvingCell.classList.add('omschrijving');
    omschrijvingCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var prijsCell = document.createElement('td');
    prijsCell.textContent = s.waarde;
    prijsCell.classList.add('prijs')
    prijsCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var aantalCell = document.createElement('input');
    aantalCell.type = "number"
    aantalCell.defaultValue = s.aantal; 
    aantalCell.addEventListener("change", eentjeMeer);
    aantalCell.classList.add('aantal')
    aantalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var totaalCell = document.createElement('td');
    totaalCell.textContent = s.total;
    totaalCell.classList.add('total')
    totaalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    r.appendChild(omschrijvingCell);
    r.appendChild(prijsCell);
    r.appendChild(aantalCell);
    r.appendChild(totaalCell);

    t.appendChild(r);

}
/////Functions//////
function getNewInput() {
    const naamValue = document.getElementById('naam').value;
    const waardeValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prijs').value);
    const qtyValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value);
    return [{ omschrijving: naamValue , waarde: waardeValue , aantal: qtyValue , total: waardeValue * qtyValue }]
}

function eentjeMeer() {
    const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('aantal');
        uitKomst = myTable.getElementsByClassName("total");
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            uitKomst[i].innerHTML = inputs[i].value * products[i].waarde; 
            console.log(products[i].waarde); 
            
        }  

     //Totaal alle producten 
const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
    return productCal.total + currentTotal
 }, 0);
 document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2); 
    
}    

function updateTable() {
    const newInput = getNewInput(); 
    products.push(newInput); 
    for (var i = 0; i < newInput.length; i++) {
        var s = newInput[i];
        var r = document.createElement('tr');

        
    r.dataset.productID = s.id; //ff beter kijken wat dit is, dit is wel cool.
    r.id = s.omschrijving + "--row"; //ff checken hoe dat gaat --row geef dus IDS mee

    var omschrijvingCell = document.createElement('td');
    omschrijvingCell.textContent = s.omschrijving;
    omschrijvingCell.classList.add('omschrijving');
    omschrijvingCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var prijsCell = document.createElement('td');
    //prijsCell.type = "number"
    prijsCell.textContent = s.waarde;
    prijsCell.classList.add('prijs');
    prijsCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var aantalCell = document.createElement('input');
    aantalCell.type = "number"
    aantalCell.defaultValue = s.aantal; 
    aantalCell.addEventListener("change", eentjeMeer);
    aantalCell.classList.add('aantal');
    aantalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var totaalCell = document.createElement('td');
    totaalCell.textContent = s.total;
    totaalCell.classList.add('total');
    totaalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    r.appendChild(omschrijvingCell);
    r.appendChild(prijsCell);
    r.appendChild(aantalCell);
    r.appendChild(totaalCell);

    t.appendChild(r);
   
    console.log(products[4]); // het word geen string zie ik hier.
        
        }
    };

function CalculateTot() {
    const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
        return productCal.total + currentTotal
    }, 0);
    document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2);
    // allTotal.splice(0,1, total.toFixed(2));
    // document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   allTotal;
}

//Vraag , in for loops altijd var ?
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
 
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
 
button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
 
#table {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
 
th, td , input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;

}

#totaal {

    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
    <title>Boodschappenlijst</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Boodschappenlijst </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="table"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Naam</p>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="naam" /><br />
        <p>Aantal</p>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="qty" /><br />
        <p>Prijs</p>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="prijs" /><br/><br />
    <input type="button" value="Add Product" onclick="updateTable()" id="add"><br /><br />
    <div id="totaal"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `getNewInput()` function. You return an array, while you should return an object. Change this:

```
return [{ omschrijving: naamValue , waarde: waardeValue , aantal: qtyValue , total: waardeValue * qtyValue }]
```

to this:

```
return { omschrijving: naamValue , waarde: waardeValue , aantal: qtyValue , total: waardeValue * qtyValue }
```

And accordingly, modify the `updateTable()` function by removing the for-loop.

And everything will work fine:

```js
const myTable = document.getElementById('table')
let products = [ 
    { omschrijving: "Brood" , waarde: 1 , aantal:3 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Brocolli" , waarde: 0.99 , aantal: 2 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Krentenbollen" , waarde: 1.20 , aantal: 4 , total: 0},
    { omschrijving: "Noten" , waarde: 2.99 , aantal: 2 , total: 0}
]
///Update totals in tabel
TabelTotals();
function TabelTotals() {
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].total = products[i].waarde * products[i].aantal;  
}

}
Alles();
function Alles(){
//Totaal alle producten 
const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
   return productCal.total + currentTotal
}, 0);
document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2); 
}
////Table /////Headers
const headerTexts = ['Name', 'Prijs', 'Aantal', 'Totaal'];
const t = document.createElement('table');
t.appendChild(document.createElement('thead'));
t.querySelector('thead').appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));

for (var i = 0; i < headerTexts.length; i++) {
    const heading = document.createElement('td');
    heading.textContent = headerTexts[i];
    t.querySelector('thead tr').appendChild(heading);
}
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(t);
//Rows
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var s = products[i];
    var r = document.createElement('tr');

    r.dataset.productID = s.id; //ff beter kijken wat dit is, dit is wel cool.
    r.id = s.omschrijving + "--row"; 

    var omschrijvingCell = document.createElement('td');
    omschrijvingCell.textContent = s.omschrijving;
    omschrijvingCell.classList.add('omschrijving');
    omschrijvingCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var prijsCell = document.createElement('td');
    prijsCell.textContent = s.waarde;
    prijsCell.classList.add('prijs')
    prijsCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var aantalCell = document.createElement('input');
    aantalCell.type = "number"
    aantalCell.defaultValue = s.aantal; 
    aantalCell.addEventListener("change", eentjeMeer);
    aantalCell.classList.add('aantal')
    aantalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var totaalCell = document.createElement('td');
    totaalCell.textContent = s.total;
    totaalCell.classList.add('total')
    totaalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    r.appendChild(omschrijvingCell);
    r.appendChild(prijsCell);
    r.appendChild(aantalCell);
    r.appendChild(totaalCell);

    t.appendChild(r);

}
/////Functions//////
function getNewInput() {
    const naamValue = document.getElementById('naam').value;
    const waardeValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('prijs').value);
    const qtyValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('qty').value);
    return { omschrijving: naamValue , waarde: waardeValue , aantal: qtyValue , total: waardeValue * qtyValue }
}

function eentjeMeer() {
    const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('aantal');
        uitKomst = myTable.getElementsByClassName("total");
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            uitKomst[i].innerHTML = inputs[i].value * products[i].waarde; 
            console.log(products[i].waarde); 
            
        }  

     //Totaal alle producten 
const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
    return productCal.total + currentTotal
 }, 0);
 document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2); 
    
}    

function updateTable() {
    const newInput = getNewInput(); 
    products.push(newInput);
    var s = newInput;
    var r = document.createElement('tr');

        
    r.dataset.productID = s.id; //ff beter kijken wat dit is, dit is wel cool.
    r.id = s.omschrijving + "--row"; //ff checken hoe dat gaat --row geef dus IDS mee

    var omschrijvingCell = document.createElement('td');
    omschrijvingCell.textContent = s.omschrijving;
    omschrijvingCell.classList.add('omschrijving');
    omschrijvingCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var prijsCell = document.createElement('td');
    //prijsCell.type = "number"
    prijsCell.textContent = s.waarde;
    prijsCell.classList.add('prijs');
    prijsCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var aantalCell = document.createElement('input');
    aantalCell.type = "number"
    aantalCell.defaultValue = s.aantal; 
    aantalCell.addEventListener("change", eentjeMeer);
    aantalCell.classList.add('aantal');
    aantalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    var totaalCell = document.createElement('td');
    totaalCell.textContent = s.total;
    totaalCell.classList.add('total');
    totaalCell.dataset.productID = s.id;

    r.appendChild(omschrijvingCell);
    r.appendChild(prijsCell);
    r.appendChild(aantalCell);
    r.appendChild(totaalCell);

    t.appendChild(r);
   
    console.log(products[4]); // het word geen string zie ik hier.
};

function CalculateTot() {
    const total = products.reduce((currentTotal, productCal) => {
        return productCal.total + currentTotal
    }, 0);
    document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   total.toFixed(2);
    // allTotal.splice(0,1, total.toFixed(2));
    // document.getElementById('totaal').innerHTML = "Totaal bedrag  " +   allTotal;
}

//Vraag , in for loops altijd var ?
```

```css
body {
    text-align: center;
}
 
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
 
button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
 
#table {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
 
th, td , input {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;

}

#totaal {

    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: skyblue;
    padding: 5px;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  
    <title>Boodschappenlijst</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Boodschappenlijst </h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="table"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Naam</p>
    <input type="text" name="item" id="naam" /><br />
        <p>Aantal</p>
    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="qty" /><br />
        <p>Prijs</p>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="prijs" /><br/><br />
    <input type="button" value="Add Product" onclick="updateTable()" id="add"><br /><br />
    <div id="totaal"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Omg! That is so simple ! I did that before, but I did not remove the for loop. I did not see where I went wrong because it just crashed ! Now next time I will remember that if it does not show anything in the console, and it acts weird. It is probably a faulty for loop ! Thanks so much ! I learned from this :)